# ActiveDirectoryClient throwing both Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataErrorException AND System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryException

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I was playing with ActiveDirectoryClient to call ADGraph APIs, and I found out that it is throwing **System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryException** on my local machine (wrapped within an Exception), but it is throwing **Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataErrorException** on one of our deployed service instead.

I cannot find any Documentation regarding what exceptions ActiveDirectoryClient is supposed to throw, and how we are supposed to handle exceptions given this erratic behavior.

I looked at the de-compiled code, and it seems like this is due to namespace conflict between **System.Data.Services.Client** vs. **Microsoft.Data.Services.Client**, but I am not 100% sure.

Can anyone help me understand which type of exceptions are ActiveDirectoryClient supposed to throw, and why this is throwing different kinds of exceptions depending on environment?

Here is the example stacktrace between two:

```
Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataErrorException: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation. ---> System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryException: An error occurred while processing this request. ---> System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException: {"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."}}}
   at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseAsyncResult.EndExecute[T](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.EndExecuteQuery[TElement](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.EndExecuteQuery[TElement](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.EndExecute[TElement](Object source, DataServiceContext context, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Extensions.DataServiceContextWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4c`2.<ExecuteAsync>b__4a(IAsyncResult r)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
```

vs.

```
System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryException: An error occurred while processing this request. ---> System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException: {"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."},"requestId":"babeee64-a5b1-4b37-9124-a3e18cc304fb","date":"2018-06-12T04:22:53"}}
   at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseAsyncResult.EndExecute[T](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.EndExecuteQuery[TElement](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.EndExecuteQuery[TElement](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.EndExecute[TElement](Object source, DataServiceContext context, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Extensions.DataServiceContextWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4c`2.<ExecuteAsync>b__4a(IAsyncResult r)
```

Comment: I am searching for this answer too, it's worth noting the InnerException of DataServiceQueryException has a message with JSON - containing the odata.error . Maybe it silently tries to deserialize this to a ODataErrorException and fails. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No, I just ended up having to handle both types of exceptions :(

Comment: Likewise, I now deserialize the message to an ODataError and rethrow. Not pretty. I was only seeing this on when quering a user by upn (GetUser). I'm relying on ODataErrorException being thrown for other queries - have you seen this across the board? If not, what was the nature of your query? Thanks for responding.

Comment: I am querying to get roles for a user, and get subscribedSkus for a tenant. It only happens in certain environments (cannot reprod it in my local machine, but occurs on deployed machine), so I am not sure what is the core issue here...

Answer (score 0):

In both your exception there is very clear message:

`{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."}`

You do not have enough privileges to complete the operation. So consult the graph API regarding the operation you try to accomplish, what privileges does it require and if you have granted those to your application.

Also take a note that if you are using just client credentials flow you will not be able to delete any objects from your directory. The applications (service principals) aren't allowed to delete anything. You can also overcome this, but you do not want to do that. The way to make application capable of deleting objects, is to make it company administrator. That means, anyone who got your client credentials (client_id, client_secret) will have full control of your Azure AD. And you do not want that.